# How to Change Prefix and set Number in Table Caption

Tags: tables, captions

I want to change the prefix of my Table from 'Table 1' to 'S 3' the document only consists only of that Table so I would need to set the number myself. I tried the set caption command but that only fixes the 'Table' into 'S' problem but not the '1' to '3' problem. I would be very thankful for every hint.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=26mm,top=26mm,right=26mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx,ragged2e, caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}\captionsetup[table]{name=S1 Descriptives Table}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{}

    \begin{tabular}{lll}
          \textbf{}&\textbf{Mean/Prop.(unimputed) \tnote{1}}&     \textbf{Range} \\
      \toprule
\textbf{test test test} & 3.157  (0.044) & {0-12} \\
\textbf{test test test} & 25.8\%    &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] These values were calculated using weighted and imputed data.
\end{tablenotes}

\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do `\captionsetup[table]{name=S3 Descriptives Table}`, then there is an `S3` instead of `S1`, and if you do `\setcounter{table}{2}` before `\begin{table}` (say) the table will have number 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which (a) modifies the LaTeX macros `\tablename` and `\thetable` and (b) sets the table number to the intended number minus 1 immediately before the (otherwise unremarkable) `\caption` statement. This approach preserves the possibility of creating cross-references via the usual `\label`/`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=26mm,top=26mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, 
              justification   = justified,
              labelsep        = space}  % <-- new
\renewcommand\tablename{S}
% Omit the next instruction if you want whitespace between "S" and the number:
\renewcommand\thetable{\unskip\arabic{table}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setcounter{table}{2} % intended number minus 1
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Descriptive Table}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
  \textbf{}&\textbf{Mean/Prop. (unimputed)\tnote{1}}&     \textbf{Range} \\
  \toprule
  \textbf{test test test} & 3.157  (0.044) & 0--12 \\
  \textbf{test test test} & 25.8\%         &  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
  \footnotesize
  \item[1] These values were calculated using weighted and imputed data.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```